# Java build a list from two other lists with different objects and common property

Tags: java, list, java-stream, equals, contains

I am trying to build a list with a common property from two other lists of different objects. I am using the Stream library but I can not make the code work. Here is what I have tried:

Attempt 1 (this returns only the first element of the ObjectAList):

```
private List<ObjectA> getFilteredObjectAList() {

    return ObjectAList.stream()
            .filter(a -> a.getProperty().getPropertyId().equals(
                    (ObjectBList.stream().map(b -> b.getPropertyId())).findAny().orElse(null)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Attempt 2 (this raises error "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface"):

```
private List<ObjectA> getFilteredObjectAList() {
     List<ObjectA> list;
     ObjectAList.stream()
     .forEach(a -> a.getProperty().getPropertyId()
     .filter((ObjectBList.stream()
     .map((b -> b.getPropertyId())::contains ? list.add(t) : "".isEmpty())))
     .collect(Collectors.toList()));
     return list;
     }
```

Your help is so much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to return `ObjectA` instances where the value `getProperty().getPropertyId()` exists in some list of `ObjectB` values.

Your first attempt doesn't work because it compares `getPropertyId` of each `ObjectA` with `getPropertyId` of a random `ObjectB` (because you're calling `findAny`).

You want something like this:

```
private List<ObjectA> getFilteredObjectAList() {
    return ObjectAList.stream()
            .filter(a -> ObjectBList.stream().matchAny(b -> b.getPropertyId() ==
                a.getProperty().getPropertyId())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

However, this approach could be slow if the lists are large, because you're scanning the `ObjectB` list once for very member of the `ObjectA` list. You're better off constructing a `HashSet` of the IDs that exist in the `ObjectB` list, then looking up the values from the `ObjectA` list in that set.

```
private List<ObjectA> getFilteredObjectAList() {
    Set<String> ids = ObjectBList.stream().map(ObjectB::getPropertyId)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
    return ObjectAList.stream()
            .filter(a-> ids.contains(a.getProperty().getPropertyId())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you dear Willis. I am going to try this out. I spend the whole day thinking about a solution, your help is invaluable! Thank you,